# Is it required to include "Disagree" buttons for terms of service?

Tags: contract-law, international, terms-of-service

When installing software applications for the first time, there's usually a prompt to accept/reject the terms of service. Accepting the terms grant access to the service while disagreeing closes the application and prevents access.

A software we recently built doesn't include the "Disagree" button and I recently got into an argument with a colleague who insisted that by law, you are required to give the user the option of disagreeing in addition to accepting the terms.

Is this true?

Comment: I assume that the software will not install until you agree: is that what you're saying? Then how do they exit the installation routine, or do that just have to power the computer off?

Comment: @user6726: Instead of powering the computer off, they could have the default "X"/close window button in the corner, with it being an implicit, but not explicit disagreement.

Comment: This is not a legal issue, but probably a software usability issue. Some forms present a "Continue" button that is disabled until you click on the "Agree" check box. Some go so far as to keep the Continue button disabled until you actually scroll through or print the agreement text. Not including a "Disagree" option may or may not be a good move for usability, but very unlikely to be illegal. See also: [Best practise to ask for Terms of Service agreement in an app](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/112455/best-practise-to-ask-for-terms-of-service-agreement-in-an-app)